# Can I use JPA 2.0 with Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, eclipselink

Can I use JPA 2.0(e.g EclipseLink) with Google App Engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DataNucleus plugin to the Google AppEngine supports both the JDO and JPA API to access Google AppEngine Datastore infrastructure. Currently this implementation seems to support JPA1 only.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't use any implementation on GAE and they only support JPA 1.0. Quoting [Using JPA with App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/usingjpa.html):

> The App Engine Java SDK includes an implementation of JPA 1.0 for the App Engine datastore. The implementation is based on DataNucleus Access Platform.

Answer (score 2):

"Experimental" support for JPA 2.0 is now available in GAE.

[You can find out how to set it up here.](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jpa/overview-dn2)

Answer (score 1):

Now, in version 1.7.1 of GAE SDK you can use JPA 2 or JDO 3, fully supported. See [release notes](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com.br/2012/08/app-engine-171-released.html). Or set up using [this information](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jpa/overview-dn2).