# JPA 1 @Embedded on accessor method returning Interface type

Tags: jpa, interface

I want to use @Embedded on an accessor method that returns Interface type rather than actual impl but it seems that JPA doesn't support that.

Got some pointers while searching that i have to use abstract classes but couldn't figure it to work.

Example

```
interface IEmail{  
    String getLocalPart();  
    String getDomainPart();   
    String getEmailAddress();  
}

class Email implements IEmail{
    @Transient
    String getLocalPart(){}
    @Transient
    String getDomainPart(){}  
    @Column(..) 
    String getEmailAddress(){}
}

interface IUser{
   IEmail getEmail();
}

class User implements IUser{   
    @Embedded 
    IEmail getEmail(){}
}
```

I would like not to use abstract classes as interfaces are in a separate project (that has no dependency on JPA jar) and impl are in separate project so if i define Email as abstract class in interface project, i can't use JPA annotations.

Please assist.

p.s. a. am not using Hibernate impl so can't use @Target to solve this problem
     b. am using this in AppEngine platform
     c. haven't tried this yet in my app but i know it wont work as earlier i got error when working  with Hibernate and got it resolved via @Target annotation

---

@becomputer06
Thanks for detailed reply.
Unfortunately, AppEngine supports JPA 1.0 only as of now (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045148/can-i-use-jpa-2-0-with-google-app-engine))

So i fear i can't use @Access annotation.

@Bozho as mentioned, i just want to embed a class into another but by specifying Interface types. Please ask more if needed.

@Datanucleus yes, i saw your comments in other posts. i do understand but we are settled in JPA for some reasons (atleast we are bit familiar to it - earlier we worked on JPA + Hibernate)

Any other pointers? Thanks again

Comment: JPA doesn't support persisting fields/properties that are (instances of) interfaces. Only JDO allows that.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like not to use abstract
>   classes as interfaces are in a
>   separate project (that has no
>   dependency on JPA jar) and impl are in
>   separate project so if i define Email
>   as abstract class in interface
>   project, i can't use JPA annotations.

- If you annotate a getter method with
  `@Embeddable` AND the class with
  `@Access(value=AccessType.PROPERTY)`,
  make sure you annotate the
  corresponding field with
  `@Access(value=AccessType.FIELD)` to override its default AccessType (which is same as class's AccessType).
- If a getter method returns an interface type AND the class is annotated with 
  `@Access(value=AccessType.FIELD)`, then annotate the matching field with `@Embeddable` (by default the access type of such field is same as class's AccessType).

**IEmail**

```
public interface IEmail {
    String getEmailAddress();
    void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress);
}
```

**Email**

```
@Embeddable
public class Email implements IEmail, Serializable {
    private String emailAddress;

    public String getEmailAddress() {
        return emailAddress;
    }
    public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }
}
```

**IUser**

```
public interface IUser {
    String getId();
    String getUserName();
    IEmail getEmail();
}
```

**User** is Annotated with @Access(value=AccessType.PROPERTY)

```
@Entity
@Access(value=AccessType.PROPERTY)
public class User implements IUser {

    private String id;
    private String userName;

    @Access(value=AccessType.FIELD)
    private Email email;

    @Id
@GeneratedValue 
    public long getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(long id) { this.id = id; }
    public String getUserName() { return userName; }
    public void setUserName(String userName) { this.userName = userName; }

    @Embedded
    public IEmail getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(IEmail email) {
        if(email instanceof Email) {
            this.email = (Email) email;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("not a valid type");
        }
    }

}
```

**User** is Annotated with @Access(value=AccessType.FIELD)

```
@Entity
@Access(value=AccessType.FIELD)
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue() 
    private long id;

    private String userName;

    @Embedded
    private Email email;

    public long getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(long id) { this.id = id; }
    public String getUserName() { return userName; }
    public void setUserName(String userName) { this.userName = userName; }

    public IEmail getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(IEmail email) {
        if(email instanceof Email) {
            this.email = (Email) email;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("not a valid type");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to answer some of the questions however your example completely defeats the purpose of the IEMail interface, by requiring the a known impl.

```
if(email instanceof Email) {
    this.email = (Email) email;
} else {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("not a valid type");
 }
```

Hibernate is able to do this with the component and composite-id mappings

```
<composite-id name="id" class="org.adligo.models.core.client.ids.LongIdentifierMutant">
              <key-property name="id" column="tid"/>
        </composite-id>
        <component name="item_id" class="org.adligo.models.core.client.ids.LongIdentifierMutant" >
                <property name="id" column="item_id"/>
        </component>
```

How to do this in JPA?